# "Class 'App\User' not found" with Laravel Chatter

Tags: php, laravel

I've recently updated my app from Laravel 5.1 to 5.3.

Soon after this, I tried installing chatter.

I followed the instructions, found here: https://github.com/thedevdojo/chatter

After following all the steps, I went to check out the page localhost/forums, and it returned this error:

[image]

I think the root cause of this is because I don't use the default Laravel Authentication. I have my own Auth controllers, user model, etc.

Is there any way I could get around this without using the default Laravel Authentication Scaffolding?

Answer (score 0):

It's in `vendor/devdojo/chatter/src/Models/Discussion.php` at line 15.

The model `Discussion` is defining a One To Many (Inverse) Relationship with `User` Model at `App\User` ( app/User.php ) but `User` model isn't there. That's the problem.

You can create a `User` model in your `app` folder.

If you want to use `User` model from another directory.
U can extend your model like

```
use To\Your\Directory\User;

class User extends User
{
```

Answer (score 0):

The Chatter package utilizes the default Laravel authentication functionality.  If you dig into their codebase you'll notice references to the Auth facade and Eloquent models in many files/classes.  Consequentially, it would be necessary to implement the default authentication in order to use Chatter.  The most you can customize is the namespace of the User model in Chatter's own config [file](https://github.com/thedevdojo/chatter/blob/master/config/chatter.php).

Answer (score 0):

In `config\chatter.php` I changed the default namespace location in the user array from  `App\User` to my own user model.